# Multiline notifications

Tags: android, notifications, multiline

I need to display a few lines of text in the notification. The minimum Android SDK is 4.0.3. or Level 15, however "big notifications" are only available from level 16.

What can I do to show all lines in the notification for API level 15?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748107/1265724

Comment: @Ram kiran Unfortunately I don't see how I can implement this for SDK level >= 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
```

I didn't test it on Android 4.0.3, but I am not getting any compiler- or lint-errors.