# Using GCM service in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

**What I am doing:**

- I am using push notification to recieve notifications.
- I have used the code below
- I also have declared necessary permissions in manifest

**What is happening:**

- I am able to recieve the notification
- But when the new notification comes, old one is replaced

**What I am trying to do:**

- Say first notification is recieved
- When the second notification comes old one should not be replaced
  instead both should be shown

---

**GCMNotificationIntentService.java**

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "+ extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "+ extras.get(Keys.MSG_KEY));
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
        }

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        /*Toast.makeText(context, "notification_Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();*/
    }

    private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getExtras()!=null){

            Bundle message = intent.getExtras();
            String s= message.getString("the_message");
            final Intent emptyIntent = new Intent(context,ActMain.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1234, emptyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.screenname_apptitle))
                    .setContentText(s)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

             // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light            
            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());

            /*Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    "\n message : " + message, 1).show();*/

            NotificationManager objNotfManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
int notification_id = (int) date.getTime();
notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);
```

use timestamp id instead of final value for notification id

Answer (score 1):

It is replacing the old one because the notification id is same for all notification. So when you try to add a new notification it replaces the old one instead of adding a new one.

```
notificationManager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());
```

this line is the problem and you are sending 1234 as notification id for all notifications, replace this line with 
`notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build());`

If you want diferent notification for different push add different notification id.
You can set a inbox mode to the notifications as well so that a group of notifications are visible under one just like gmail see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748049/android-multiple-line-notification-like-gmail-app)

For better understanding of notification see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());
```

to

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

It should have a unique number. Hope this will help