# Setting a Recyclerview into a notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

unable to add list view in notification using remote views,is there any other way to display list view in notification bar as notification. Unable to add list view in remote view, Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `RecyclerView` in Notification.

If you want to show your data like whatsapp multiple message in notification, that is called **Clubing**.

Here is an example for Clubbing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34961716/6676466

hope it will help you.

Comment: I am creating custom layout for notification,where i have added listview .,is there any possible solution

Comment: Any idea for listview can we add in custom layout for notification

Comment: No you can not add ListView in notification, it does not allow, but Why you want to add listview..? what is the purpose of adding in ListView...?