# Notification with action buttons

Tags: android, notifications

How I can create notification with action buttons like Gmail app notification?

[Notification with action buttons sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiNwC.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Check the below link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748049/android-multiple-line-notification-like-gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code

```
 public void createNotification() {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.reply, "reply", pIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

    }
```

Comment: But this addAction method available in android 22 and above, how I can handle this in older versions? @Avinash

Comment: you can try NotificationCompat.Builder instead of notification