# Putting an View object in notification android

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to put a View object (such as TextView, Edittext, Button, etc) in a notification in Android. I am new to this assignment and I am confused so here is my attempt so far.

So I have a notification to appear as following:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("Message From")
        .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "", pIntent).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                  (NotificationManager)   
                    context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

I know this can be done for Jelly Bean and after version. I was wondering if its possible to insert a  View object possibly through PendingIntent using Intent?

If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html didn't the "Custom Notification Layouts" helped you?

Answer (score 1):

see these

http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/

[Create custom notification, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168553/create-custom-notification-android)