# Setting a single line android notification (only title)

Tags: android, vertical-alignment, android-notifications

I want to set a notification for my app in the notifications drawer, but only with a title in it (no body), meaning - only one line of notification, which should be vertically aligned to the app icon.

For example, in the following notification I'd like to keep only the "Ringer shushed 'til 19:16" title, in the same font size, but vertically centered to the app icon on the left.

[image]

Here is my code for creating the notification:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

PendingIntent deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, GCMIntentService.class)
                        .setAction(IntentConsts.ACTION_CLEAR_MESSAGE_COUNT), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

manager.notify(MMConfig.NTF_ID_GCM, new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
                .setContentTitle("My title")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
                .build());
```

Right now I succeed creating the notification with only title in it, but I can't seem to make it vertically centered with the app icon. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen another app that has achieved this?

Comment: Do you mean vertically **centered**? It looks like Google Now has single line notifications, but they are not centered.

Comment: @weston no, but it seems like a classic thing to do, and I didn't see any documentation about it.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier yeah, vertically centered.

Comment: check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16168704/383414 for how to do a custom layout.

Comment: So you don't want the text "Select it to turn it on now" as in the image?

Comment: @Tapeshvar no, I want it to the side of the image, but vertically aligned with the image (center aligned to the height of the notification).

Comment: @limlim: Could you add an image sample of your expected result edited using paint or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like some suggested, I used `RemoteViews` to customize my notification, as following:

```
final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_new_message);

views.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);

Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.contentView = views;
notification.icon = R.drawable.push_icon;
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

manager.notify(Config.NTF_ID_GCM, notification);
```

Where I set inside my `notification_new_message.xml` the desirable look of my notification.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible.
Even I tried some ways of achieving your idea. But nothing does seem to work the way you want.
As far as considering the alignment I don't think its practically possible that too in the vertical alignment.
Even if you try removing the Title Still the place for the Title is filled with blank space which covers more than half of your notification area, so even with that...still the body of the notification doesn't seem to be proper center aligned.

Also I tried aligning the content of a text view and then using this for the value within the setLatestEventInfo(), still not even the horizontal alignment seems to be working as far as notifications are considered.

I might be wrong, still with the level of research I went through it doesn't seem to be possible. Lemme know if there is any alternative ways found:P