# How to get the ui elements in a notification [Android]

Tags: android

I am trying to access the text on each button on a notification - and do further processing on the same.

I have the `RemoteView` object :

```
RemoteView rView = mStatusBarNotification.getNotification().contentView;
```

is it possible to get the text on each button using this `RemoteView` Object? If yes, how?

For example, in the following notification i need the text "Speaker" "End"

[image: phone notification screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

See [Create custom notification, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168553/create-custom-notification-android) or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Is there a way to reverse engineer the elements in the notification?

Comment: Why would you like to reverse engineer the elements? As far as I know you can only connect to your own notifications.