# Android GCM Creating Notifications on its own

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I setup GCM and it works fine. I get notifications from the server and they are shown to the client. The problem is, GCM creates its own notification and wont let me make a custom one. I followed this guide: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging.

Here is my service code:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");

        createNotification(from, message);
    }

    private void createNotification(String title, String body) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, RouteActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(RouteActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Anything helps.

Comment: What do you want to change exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs

> Message payload is optional. If you are including a payload in the message, use the data parameter to include your custom key/value
>   pairs. The client app handles the data payload for display or other
>   processing purposes.
>
> **The notification parameter with predefined options indicates that GCM
>   will display the message on the client app’s behalf if the client app
>   implements GCMListenerService on Android**, or whenever the notification
>   message is sent to an iOS device. The app server can send a message
>   including both notification and data payloads. In such cases, GCM
>   handles displaying the notification payload and the client app handles
>   the data payload. For more information and examples, see

in other words if you send in your payload a `notification` tag GCM will create a notification for your app

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server

Answer (score 0):

Custom layout for notifications in Android, if that's what you mean: [Create custom notification, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168553/create-custom-notification-android)

Comment: No, the above code in the createNotification method is not run. I can remove that and I will still get a notification.