# Android - Notification BigPictureStyle

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to display the notification like this [image: like this]

but im getting like this[image: like this]

Im using the code

```
final Notification notifyDetails = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .setContentTitle(mTitle)
                                .setContentText(mDesc)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setTicker(mDesc)
                                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                                        .bigPicture(myBitmap)
                                        .setSummaryText(mDesc))
                                .setContentIntent(nIntent)
                                .addAction(R.drawable.share, "Share", nIntent)
                                .build();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

How can display my notification like that? I have google it, i didnt get solution. please anyone worked on this, please share your idea.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is the difference you want to achieve?

Comment: content text should be bottom and the share action should be top and background white should not display....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16168704/1979882 read this . you have to use custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need the custom UI for notification.
Refer to the below link for more details on it.

[Custom Notification](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(bm) 
                .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
                .setContentText("Events received")
```

Please note large icon must be a bitmap